# Why dialogflow cant recognize CNY？

Tags: dialogflow-es

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mNmb.png)

Why dialogflow cant recognize CNY？

Comment: Hi, I’ve also tried this on my end and I was able to replicate the issue as well.
This might be a potential issue with Dialogflow’s sys.currency-name entity, It would be best to report this to Google through one of the support channels listed at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/getting-support.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Chinese language, I dare giving the following answer based on my observations.

In the image, a single training phrase has two parameters with same name with two different values for `@sys.currency-name`, what is strange to me is that both parameters are highlighted with purple. I think a parameter name was changed to have the same name than the other (which is not correct due to they have different values). By having the same parameter name with two different values I think Dialogflow will decide which one to return or combine.

Please try to change the parameter names with `currency-name-1` and `currency-name-2`. Most probably Dialogflow will return each value (USD and CNY) in a different parameter. I think this should fix the behavior because [`@sys.currency-name`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities) is an [ISO 4217](https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml) string where CNY is already included.